# HP Deskjet F 4180 combi works with Ubuntu 14.04 but not Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, printing, hp

HP Deskjet F 4180 combi works with Ubuntu 14.04 but not Lubuntu 14.04. My MSI K9VGM mobo is quite old, about 8 years, but want to keep it as I use XP dual boot.

Lubuntu print settings system-config-printer recognises it as one of the 4100 series after I installed the recommended drivers, (which were for an HP F 9XXX for some reason) but when I press print nothing happens.

If I go through the troubleshoot section it won't print test page. After debugging a huge list of error messages is thrown up.

Answer (score 0):

I did a google search for drivers and found the hplip website. Looked daunting at first but had no alternative but to go through with it and did the automatic install and all seems to be working, although I got this warning:
PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
  set_interactive(1)
I don't know what this means, but everything is working any way.

Comment: If this is not your answer please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/701950/edit) your question to update it.

Comment: It is my own answer. Surely that is clear? And what would be the point of editing the question? Have I missed something?

Comment: I just confuse you make another question in your answer " Could anyone say what thismeans " .

Comment: Aah! Now I see! Thank you, I think you are correct. Will work on this later